# Chart.js doughnut text colors

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

How do you change the doughnut text color and doughnut filler colors separately? I have something like this:

```
var  color = [ "#3F9F3F", "#FFFFFF" ];
var chartData =  {
  label :  myLabels, 
  data : myData,
  colors : color
};
```

The second color attribute overrides anything else I've tried. What property, for donuts specifically, will fix this?

[image]

I'd like the text color to be different from the black color in the chart.

**Edit:**

This is a jsfiddle I found that shows a basic chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/6xV78/

The question is, how do you change the font color inside the doughnut?

**Edit 2:**

Realized the text color inside the donuts, while affected by the secondary color, was actually painted using canvas.fillText(). As such, all I needed was to add .fillStyle = "whatever" and it works.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?  I'm used to seeing data defined as an array of objects with the value, label, and color [{value:5,label:'text',color:'#FFFFFF'}].  I'm not sure how your structure would be used.

Comment: I found a jsfiddle that shows a basic doughnut structure and posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized the text color inside the donuts, while affected by the secondary color, was actually painted using canvas.fillText(). As such, all I needed was to add .fillStyle = "whatever" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(pieData,{percentageInnerCutout : 80});
```

by

```
    var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(pieData,doughnutOptions);
```

You can find all the available options here http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration

For you color text you can add this option

```
var doughnutOptions= {
 scaleLabel: '<p style="color: red"><%=value%></p>'
}
```

Change `style="color: red"` by the color you want

Comment: I've added "scaleFontColor: "#00FF00" but it doesn't work, any reason why?

Comment: Try to use all the possible options like in the link I provided. If it doesn't work, I have no clue why... sorry

Comment: This does not get parsed properly on output. Ends up showing HTML tags